# How worried should I be about port 22?

Tags: ssh, password

I am learning Hadoop and I need to ssh onto localhost in order to set up a pseudo distributed system. I read on another forum:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/ssh-connect-to-host-localhost-port-22-connection-refused-935331/

...that doing so by installing openssh-server would open up port 22 to the internet, which makes sense.

My question is:

Is the password that I use when I execute

```
sudo *somecommand*
```

the one that a hacker would need to crack in order to access information on my computer? And (just one more) if this is the case, how do I make a secure password that isn't a pain to type out every time I use sudo? Preferably I would like to have the sudo password be short and the "port 22" password be something ridiculous and very long

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different things you can do to improve security on port 22 (the SSH server).

1. Move it to a different port - one that is unlikely to be targetted by brute force scripts.  For example, 2922, or 31822.
2. Allow only certain users access to SSH.  This can be accomplished with an AllowUsers directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
3. Allow only certain IP address ranges to connect to SSH.  This can be accomplished with your firewall software (eg ufw).
4. Rate-limit new connections to your SSH port using your firewall, for example, by using a "limit" clause in ufw.  This can reduce the rate that users can try to brute-force your server, although the SSH server does have some of its own ways of dealing with that too.
5. Ensure that all users with SSH access have a secure password.  The more characters the better.  8 or more is good, 10 or more is better.  Do allow digits and symbols on a standard keyboard.  Stress the importance of not using dictionary words, famous names or simple patterns.
6. Enforce the use of key-based authentication, where the user generates a public-private key pair on their computer and stores the public part on the SSH server, instead of allowing passwords.

Comment: Personally, after running ssh servers, IMO the biggest single thing you can do to secure your ssh server is to use ssh keys only and disable password authentication. See http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_security

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How could I forget using key based auth?  Thanks @bodhi.zazen, I'm adding it in to the answer.

Comment: @thomasrutter, Regarding the recommendation on ports 2922 and 31822, if the point is obscurity why not have all ports on each host non-standard and randomly assigned? If there is a good reason to ignore convention then shouldn't we really ignore convention? Not sarcasm. Just looking to understand.

Comment: @H2ONaCl While using a non-standard SSH port is security by obscurity, it is really effective in reducing brute-force attempts by bots, which also reduces unwanted load/traffic.  There are drawbacks though: you need to tell clients what port you are using, you tend to need to choose unprivileged "high" ports over 1024, etc.

Comment: @thomasrutter, if you have to tell clients you're using 2922 then perhaps we don't need to establish a convention around 2922.